# Pdf converted with JsPDF needs to be improved, saved on the server and sent by mail?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I'm using [JsPDF](https://parall.ax/products/jspdf) to convert a div into a PDF, using a button to commence the operation.

Here's my script :

```js
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://mrrio.github.io/jsPDF/dist/jspdf.debug.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://html2canvas.hertzen.com/build/html2canvas.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#download').click(function() {       
      html2canvas($("#canvas"), {
        onrendered: function(canvas) {         
          var imgData = canvas.toDataURL('image/png'); 
          $("#imgRes").attr("src", imgData);             
          var doc = new jsPDF('p', 'mm');
          doc.addImage(imgData, 'PNG', 10, 10);
          doc.save('sample-file.pdf');
        }
      });
    });
  });
});//]]> 
</script>
```

This is the only way I've found that worked, but if you can find a method which solves the issues then let me know.

The current problems with the script are :

1. My text in the pdf is cut (but I'd like to avoid the landscape) and
   I have only one page.
2. I need the PDF to be saved automatically in
   a folder on the server , when the page is loaded
3. I need a button to email the PDF to an email address

I know it's a lot of thing, but I'm beginning on coding and I'm a bit lost.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used HTML2PDF script.
It was better to feet my needs.
JsPDF is very good and simple to use, but the generated PDF's with a canvas / image are hard to optimize.